# tried to add a new update.secondary hook to my repos in gitolite and now git push fails

Tags: githooks, gitolite

remote: Undefined subroutine &main::repo_rights called at hooks/update line 41.
remote: error: hook declined to update

I have removed the update hook from all of my repos in order to get around this, but I know that they are now wide open.

I ran gl-setup, and I may have mixed versions of gitolite on my machine.  I am afraid that I ran the gl-setup from a version that is different than the one I am running currently.  I am not sure how to tell.  Please help. :-(

Comment: I figured it out.  I just ran the gl-setup for the older version and all is working again.

Answer (score 0):

Update, for a more recent version of Gitolite (namely a V3.x or more), the official documentation would be: "[adding your own update hooks](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/cookbook/#adding-your-own-update-hooks)", and it uses [VREFs (virtual refs)](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/vref/#virtual-refs).

> add this line in the `rc` file, within the `%RC` block, if it's not already present, or uncomment it if it's already present and commented out:
>
> ```
> LOCAL_CODE => "$ENV{HOME}/local",
> ```
>
> copy your update hook to a subdirectory called `VREF` under this directory, giving it a suitable name (let's say "`crlf`"):
>
> ```
> # log on to gitolite hosting user on the server, then:
> cd $HOME
> mkdir -p local/VREF
> cp your-crlf-update-hook local/VREF/crlf
> chmod +x local/VREF/crlf
> ```
>
> in your `gitolite-admin` clone, edit `conf/gitolite.conf` and add lines like this:
>
> ```
> -   VREF/crlf       =   @all
> ```
>
> to each repo that should have that "update" hook.
>
> Alternatively, you can simply add this at the end of the `gitolite.conf` file:
>
> ```
> repo @all
>     -   VREF/crlf       =   @all
> ```
>
> Either way, add/commit/push the change to the gitolite-admin repo.